# Forward domain to website hosted on Azure server with a non 80 port

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, cname-record

I have an Azure Ubuntu VM server with multiple websites. Say website A = 81, website B = 82. These endpoints are exposed and I can access the website externally using <ip address>:<port>.

I would like each of my websites to have a friendly domain name but in the CNAME records, I cannot specify a port - I can only specify an IP address.

Normally, this is fine because it'll just default to port 80. But I have multiple websites and therefore they cannot all be port 80 - so how can I have a domain forwarded to a Azure VM pointing to a non 80 port?

Comment: You cannot do this using DNS records. The only way would be to setup some sort of reverse proxy in front of the servers.

Comment: @JennyD : Ah ok, so how would I do that using Azure VMs?

Comment: @JennyD : sorry is this something I would do inside the VM as in have one end point pointing to 80 and then a reverse proxy installed to point to my various sites? Or some Azure configuration outside the VM?

Comment: You can do it within the VM, or with a separate server. Or you could use VirtualHosts to run all the sites on the same port.

Comment: Why don't you just use Apache name based virtual hosting? you can easily route any URL to any application directory based on the %HOST the request comes in on. so abc.com > /var/www/www.abc.com/html/index.php and xyz.com > /var/www/www.xyz.com/html/index.php

Comment: Agreed. "I have multiple websites and therefore they cannot all be port 80"... actually, they *can*; and they usually *do*.

Comment: Mmm... ok I need to figure out what this name based virtual hosting thing is. Thanks

Comment: @Massimo : I have my NGINX set up. It's working well. However, now that I have an understanding of how it works, your statement about port 80 being for all websites on the server is not technically true right? Technically, all websites on the server still has a unique port number. But what NGINX does, is it listens in on port 80 and then based on the request origin, it forwards it to localhost:<port number> with the port number of the corresponding website.

Comment: That's true in your case, because you are putting NGINX in front of your web server (it's basically acting as a reverse proxy); but you could also have configured your web server to host multiple sites on the same port and distinguish them using host headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that at the DNS level, because DNS only maps names to IP addresses and has no knowledge at all of TCP ports.

There are various solutions (a reverse proxy, multiple IP addresses...), but the simplest one would be to configure all websites to listen on port 80 and then distinguish them using host headers; since you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS, this should pose no problem at all.

You are on Ubuntu, so you're probably using Apache; [Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) are the way to go.

Comment: Not using Apache - I've got a couple of NodeJS (Meteor) apps running on this server. But I'm sure there's some sort of NodeJS version of virtual hosts

Comment: You'll be better off using nginx in front of your NodeJS applications. (@RoboShop)

Comment: @gnur : yes that's what I'm reading up on now